# Как сделать, чтобы после работы VIM не появлялись файлы типа FilName~?

Tags: vim

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы после работы VIM не появлялись файлы типа
FilName~.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно установить папку для временных файлов

```
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup//
set directory=~/.vim/backup//
```

функционал временных файлов сохранен, но в отдельной папке

Answer (score 3):

```
set nobackup
```